# importing nami-wallet package in nodejs

Tags: nami-wallet

I successfully imported and used [cardano-wallet-interface](https://github.com/HarmonicPool/cardano-wallet-interface) by harmonic pool. However, I wonder if I can directly install and import [Nami wallet](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet). I installed the package using "npm install git+{url}.git" and tried to "import * as NamiWallet from 'nami-wallet'" but I get error of index.js not found.

Main reason is that I want to check Nami further, I am getting wrong utxos when I use getUtxos() method from cardano-wallet-interface when Nami is the active wallet, however, same exact code works find when Eternl wallet is used.

Answer (score 0):

The import of Nami you are doing is not quite right. That's why you are getting that error.

I suggest you import `lucid-cardano` instead:

`npm install lucid-cardano`

[Lucid](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid) is a library which allows you to create Cardano transactions and off-chain code for your Plutus contracts in JavaScript, Deno and Node.js. It has been done by the creator of Nami Wallet so, if you want to check how it works, this will be helpful.